# Dart: Possible to exchange source code on the fly in a running system?

Tags: erlang, dart

In this [article](http://programming.oreilly.com/2013/05/dart-is-not-the-language-you-think-it-is.html) it says: "The Dart VM reads and executes source code, which means there is no compile step between edit and run.". Does that mean that you can exchange source-code on the fly in a running Dart system like in Erlang? Maybe the compiler is removed from the runtime system and then this is no longer possible. So that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

Dart is run "natively" only in Dartium, which is a flavour of Chrome with DartVM. When you develop an application you still need to compile it it to JavaScript. This way you get fast development lifecycle and in the end you can compile code to JS. Because it's compiled code there is lots more room for compiler to run optimisations on the code. So from my perspective, the compiler is still there and I don't think you would be able to replace code at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can send around source code and run it, but it would need to be in a separate isolate. Isolates do have some relationship to Erlang concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The Dart VM doesn't support [hot swapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping#Software) (Called live edit in V8). However, based on mailing list discussions, it sounds like this is something that the authors do want to support in the future.

However, as the others have mentioned, it is possible to dynamically load code into another isolate.

Comment: I see. That's interesting. Thanks.